# why iconv read more bytes than i specified

Tags: linux, unicode

I use

```
size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,   char **inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char **outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
```

to convert UTF-16BE to GB2312.

`inbytesleft` is bytes number to be convert. After conversion, `inbytesleft` is bytes number of not converted.

After one call, I found `inbytesleft` is -2, according to [iconv man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv) this function should read at most `inbytesleft`.
Who can tell my why and how to fix this?

code to be convert is

```
"保单验证"
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the return code and `errno` when that happens?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of this method, but is it possible that you specified a number of bytes that puts the cut of right in the middle of a UTF-8 character and the method has chosen to complete the character first?

Comment: @Mat return code is (size_t)-1,errno is EILSEQ,means "An invalid multibyte sequence has been encountered in the input".@Joachim Sauer,the unicode is intact,it was extracted from a PDF file and the code can be displayed by adobe reader

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the input data into your program?

I've tested the situation using this code and it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
    char data[10] = {0x4f,0xdd,0x53,0x55,0x9a,0x8c,0x8b,0xc1, 0, 0};
    char outdata[20];
    char *dataptr;
    char *outdataptr;
    iconv_t cd;
    size_t result;
    size_t inbytesleft = 8;
    size_t outbytesleft = 20;
    int i;

    cd = iconv_open("GB2312", "UTF-16BE");
    dataptr = data;
    outdataptr = outdata;
    result = iconv(cd, &dataptr, &inbytesleft, &outdataptr, &outbytesleft);
    if(result == -1)
        printf("Error: %d\n", errno);
    printf("      result: %zd\n", result);
    printf(" inbytesleft: %zd\n", inbytesleft);
    printf("outbytesleft: %zd\n", outbytesleft);

    for(i = 20; i > outbytesleft; i--){
        if(i != 20)
            printf(",");
        printf("0x%02x", *((unsigned char *)&(outdata[20-i])));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
      result: 0
 inbytesleft: 0
outbytesleft: 12
0xb1,0xa3,0xb5,0xa5,0xd1,0xe9,0xd6,0xa4
```

Which appears to be correct.

The array of items in the variable data is the UTF-16BE encoding of `保单验证`

If this doesn't help, could you post your code for analysis?

Comment: thanks for you give me your answer.I will try your code on my machine and tell you the result.BTW,could you tell me on what platform did you test? My OS is CentOS 64bit.

Comment: @PDF1001: I used Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit. Shouldn't need to use any special compile flags `gcc -o name name.c` should work fine.
I used `echo -n "保单验证"| iconv -f 'UTF-8' -t 'UTF-16BE' | hexdump -e '1/1 "0x%02x" ","'` to get the bytes (because I know that my system uses UTF-8) and tested with `echo -e \`echo 0xb1,0xa3,0xb5,0xa5,0xd1,0xe9,0xd6,0xa4| sed -r 's/,//g;s/0x/\\\\x/g'\` |iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8` to make sure I got the same result back.

Comment: @PDF1001 Any progress on this? Have you had any success?

Comment: Sorry,i tried so many times,but still not work. SO i used java to accomplish this.